# How can I get and extract a number from website using Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I want to **get and extract** the number after unixtime from this link. http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip.txt
I use below code to get data but seem it wrong

```
  public String getData() throws IOException {
String httpUrl = "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip.txt";
URL url = new URL(httpUrl);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
String response = bufferedReader.readLine();
bufferedReader.close();
```

Also, how can I test for network error by using mockito and Junit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use Java's `HttpClient` to issue a `GET` request to the URL and have it return a response as a `String`. After that, you can use a simple regular expression to extract the value that you're looking for:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("unixtime: (\\d+)", Pattern.MULTILINE);

HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .GET()
        .uri(new URI("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip.txt"))
        .build(), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(response.body());

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
1543639818
```

Just remember to handle any checked exceptions correctly.